# Using tHTTPClient component on talend to access sharepoint files

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, talend

I've used the tHTTPClient component to access files on sharepoint.

[image: job]

I chose the authentication type - "Bearer token" the token was generated from Azure Active Directory using client ID, tenant ID, and secret value without adding the "scope" key. There is no error after running the job, but I don't know how to retrieve those files. New to Talend and Azure here. Any suggestions?

[image: component description]

Comment: You should use the Graph API. Look for drives and documents.

Comment: Feel free to raise a ticket with Support as there's a feature request for official Sharepoint components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Sharepoint API to get Files, once you are authenticated and have your token.
To get a file, you can try GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method with a tFileFetch component.

Comment: you also have this article https://community.talend.com/s/article/How-to-download-a-file-from-SharePoint-using-tFileFetch-eq7eb?language=en_US (not tested)